React admin using incorrect data provider based on data being updated
I have a react admin app that has the tabbed form shown below. It handles some election data and is pretty forward. Some elections are standard and have 'candidates". Others are ballot measures and come from the 'ballotChoices' table.
Recently, I had the following error ...
An election which is set as a ballot measure (is_ballot_measure is true) properly shows the options to set the 'called_winner' option. If you select the negative option, it works fine. However, if you set the affirmative option, you get an error that react admin was trying to update the 'candidates" table for the id from the 'ballotChoices' table. Since it does not exist, an error is sent back.
I added a second affirmative option and chose it. The code behaved normally and the affirmative action is set. This just leaves the one option on this one election as not working properly and I have no idea why.
    <TabbedForm {...props}>
      <FormTab label="info">
        <SelectInput
          source="election_id"
          label="Election"
          defaultValue={electionCode}
          choices={allElections}
          disabled={true}
        />
        <TextInput source="name" label="Race Name" />
        <TextInput source="ballot_question" label="Ballot Question?" />
        <FormDataConsumer>
          {({ formData, ...rest }) => {
            if (formData.id) {
              if (formData.is_ballot_measure) {
                return (
                  <ReferenceInput
                    label="Ballot Choice"
                    source="called_winner"
                    reference="ballotChoices"
                    sort={{ field: "affirmative", order: "DESC" }}
                    filter={{ race_id: formData.id }}
                  >
                    <AutocompleteInput
                      fullWidth
                      optionText={(choice) =>
                        choice.affirmative ? "For" : "Against"
                      }
                    />
                  </ReferenceInput>
                );
              } else {
                return (
                  <ReferenceInput
                    label="Candidate"
                    source="called_winner"
                    reference="candidates"
                    sort={{ field: "first_name", order: "ASC" }}
                    filter={{ race_id: formData.id }}
                  >
                    <AutocompleteInput
                      fullWidth
                      optionText={(cand) =>
                        `${cand.first_name} ${cand.last_name}`
                      }
                    />
                  </ReferenceInput>
                );
              }
            }
          }}
        </FormDataConsumer>
        <BooleanInput source="send_to_runoff" label="Send to runoff?" />
        <BooleanInput source="uncontested" label="Uncontested?" />
        <BooleanInput source="is_clerked" label="Is this race clerked" />
        <BooleanInput source="is_primary" label="Is this a primary?" />
        <SelectInput source="party_id" label="Party" choices={allParties} />
      </FormTab>
    </TabbedForm>

These are the three options for ballotChoices and I denote which one does not work.
0 (works): {affirmative : true, createdAt:"2024-05-10T13:43:21.462Z", id: 1409, race_id: 700, text:"For2",updatedAt: "2024-05-10T13:43:21.462Z"}
1 (works) : {affirmative : false, createdAt:"2024-04-25T16:27:56.800Z", id:820, race_id: 700, text:"Against", updatedAt: "2024-04-25T16:27:56.800Z"}
2 (does not work): { affirmative : true, createdAt : "2024-04-25T16:27:55.721Z", id: 819, race_id: 700, text: "For", updatedAt: "2024-04-25T16:27:55.721Z"
So, when you choose option 2, the code is attempting to update the 'candidates' database even though the race/election has the is_ballot_measure set to true. When you choose option 0 or 1, it works fine and updates the ballotChoices table.

Neither ReferenceInput nor AutocompleteInput are supposed to trigger updates to the database. Only <Edit> will. So it's likely that the problem lies elsewhere. Could it be that you have some code outside of the form that could change the resource of the <Edit>? Or the <SaveButton>?
